# Solving an equation with a few variables for a maximum value

Tags: math, max, equation, screeps

I'm playing a game called Screeps, where you program a colony in javascript. Central to the game are little scriptable units called creeps, which can be dynamically built from different parts to give them different properties.

I've written a system of equations for determining how effective a creep will be at completing a given job by looking at its part composition.

For example, the simplified equation for a job which upgrades the colony center is:

e = 10yx / ((x + y) * (15x + 2y))

x is the number of CARRY parts on the creep.

y is the number of WORK parts on the creep.

e is the total effectiveness of the job allocation

These equations work great for determining which creeps should be given which jobs. However, I was wondering if it there is a way to solve each equation for the maximum value of e? This would give me the most effective ratio of parts to build a creep for a high demand job.

If this is possible, since I am thinking of extending the equations with another variable, say z for the number of MOVE parts, would this still be possible?

Edit: Using trial and error on the aforementioned equation

```
f(1, 1); // returns 0.294
f(1, 2); // returns 0.350
f(1, 3); // returns 0.357 --- Highest value, therefore best ratio
f(1, 4); // returns 0.347
f(1, 5); // returns 0.333
```

Can this be solved without using trial and error? If the equation had three inputs instead of 2, would a similar approach work?

Comment: What is `z`? nowhere in the math it shows `z`.

Comment: Maximizing `e` is simply setting `x` and `y` to the highest possible value, i.e., Infitinity. In your case, I doubt that it is really want you mean. Can you describe a bit more what you mean by "Maximizing `e`"? Is it using an specified point allocation, e.g., `Maximize(e) given that x+y<=n`?

Comment: Sorry, i meant e when i wrote z the first time. It's been edited now.

Comment: Okay, I'll try again. My question is how do you determine the ratio between x:y, which when inputted into the equation will result in the largest possible value for e.
The ratio is all that matters, as f(1,1) and f(2, 2) will return the same number. This is because e, the total effectiveness of the job allocation is measured in output per tick ⋅ part units.
For now, I've been using trial and error with different ratios of x and y, and selecting the one which returns the largest value of e. But there must be a better way.

Comment: Please write your explicit function for `f`.  Now it looks like you want the maximum of `10yx / (x + y) * (15x + 2y)` where `x=1`. There exists no maximum.  You probably want additional requirements, for example x and y positive and summing to 1.

Comment: I now get the impression that your equation isn't `10yx / (x + y) * (15x + 2y)` but `10yx / ((x + y) * (15x + 2y))` which is something completely different.

Comment: Yikes, I assumed they were the same equation. I've edited it now to the correct equation, with the brackets.

And, yes I do want x and y to be positive and sum to 1, as that gives me all the possible positive ratios between the the two.

Comment: "These equations work great.." is there more than one equation involved here?

Comment: And just to be clear `z` is `e` which is `f`  ... not confusing at all.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum, we can first calculate the differential, and then look where it is zero.

The maximum of your equation is at `x = (sqrt(30) - 2)/13`, or `x=0.26748, y=0.73252`.

Here is some Python code that calculates it:

```py
from sympy import evalf, solve
from sympy.abc import x, y

f = 10*y*x / ((x + y) * (15*x + 2*y))
f = f.subs(y, 1-x)  # we know x + y == 1
df = f.diff(x)
sol = solve([df], x)
print(f'solutions found: {sol}')
for s in sol:
    x0 = s[0].evalf()
    if x0 >= 0 and x0 <= 1:
        print(f'extremum at f({x0, 1-x0}) = {f.subs(x, x0).evalf()}')
```

Output:

```py
solutions found: [(-2/13 + sqrt(30)/13,), (-sqrt(30)/13 - 2/13,)]
extremum at f((0.267478890388589, 0.732521109611411)) = 0.357724784017555
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking the maximum of `e` occurs when `DIF(e,x)=0` and `DIF(e,y)=0`, where `DIF()` is the derivative. This occurs only when

```
2*y^2 = 15*x^2
```

or

```
y = sqrt(30)/2*x
```

Using the above in the expression for `e`

```
e = (170 - 20*sqrt(30))/169 = 0.3577247
```

Comment: Thanks! To answer your earlier question, z is not e - that was a mistake. I used f to refer to the function that generates e. Sorry for being unclear.

z was part of a follow up question, where you have a similar equation with three independent variables (x,y and z) instead of two, where you again solve for the maximum of e. However, in my case introducing z added the ceiling function to the equation, which complicates the problem. Since this problem is different enough, and I've made a mess of this thread, I think it would be best to simply ask this as a new question.